# How to get attributes from a JSON file to an EJS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, ejs

I have this JSON file that I use as a database called data.json.

```
{
 "car": {
 "quantity": 2,
 "price": 100
}
```

I have this code on node.js called app.js

```
var data = fs.readFileSync("data.json");
var jData = JSON.parse(data);
// console.log(jData);
 
 
////////ROUTES///////////
app.get("/", home);

// New item create path
app.get("/new/:id/:quantity/:price?", newItem);

function newItem(req, res){
 var itemData = req.params;
 ////// shows :id as name
 var newName = itemData.id;
 ////// shows :price as price
 var newPrice = Number(itemData.price);
 var newQuantity = Number(itemData.quantity);
 var reply;
 //// Object created
 function ItemObj(quantity, price) {
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.price = price;
 }
 ///// Assing attributes to object
 var createItem =  new ItemObj(newQuantity, newPrice);
 // print stuff
 res.send("This new " + newName + " has been added! and it costs " + 
 newPrice);
 ////// If prices is not set
 if(!newPrice){
 reply = ("price is required")
 //////////then---->
 } else {
  jData[newName] = createItem;
  var stringData = JSON.stringify(jData, null, 2);
  fs.writeFile("data.json", stringData, finished);
  function finished(err, info){
  console.log("updated");
  }
res.render("index", {jData: jData})
}
```

Then I have an EJS code called index.ejs and when I tring to pass the JSON database (jData) to EJS in order to show their values I get an error saying "jData is not defined"

```
 <h1>Hello bro</h1>

 <%= JSON.stringify(jData) %>
```

Where am I making a mistake and how do I get a json file to show on the index.ejs file? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case other people wonder. I was able to fix the error by setting up the jData database to a variable inside the node.js (app.js):

```
var db = jData;
res.render("index", {exampleVar: db});
```

Then, I had to modify the JSON file by using stringify() on the EJS file (index.ejs):

```
<h1> Price of item: <%= 
JSON.stringify(exampleVar["car"]["price"]) %> </h1>
```

Getting as result on the client page:

```
Price of item: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the JSON file to the file you need the data, then you have to parse it:

```
const noParsedData = { "car": { "quantity": 2, "price": 100 } }

const parsedData = JSON.parse(noParsedData)
```

When you do that, the resulting date should be an object. Now you can use the keys and values of that object in your file.

*Note: It also works for arrays.*